# drf spectacular not showing query params in swagger ui

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, swagger, swagger-ui, drf-spectacular

I have generic ListAPIView with following list request function. Here category is a query parameter. I am trying to achieve such that the swagger ui also shows the query parameter in the swagger ui doc. How to achieve this? I have the following code.

```
@extend_schema(
    parameters=[
        OpenApiParameter(name='category',location=OpenApiParameter.QUERY, description='Category Id', required=False, type=int),
    ],
)
def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    category_id = request.query_params.get('category')
    ....
    return Response(data)
```

Answer (score 5):

I agree with Insa but you can also decorate your View,
to avoid implement/override get method just to decorate it.

```py
@extend_schema_view(
    get=extend_schema(
        parameters=[
            OpenApiParameter(name='category', description='Category Id', type=int),
        ]
    )
)
class YourListView(ListAPIView):
...
```

I dropped `OpenApiParameter` location and required arguments as they equal default values.

Comment: This is the better solution, if you don't customize the method! my answer merely explained what went wrong.

Comment: This is a great solution. The only thing that doesn't quite work is that instead of parameters I passed a serializer. My parameters appear in the docs, but don appear camelized, which I have set up through drf-spectacular. Does any of you have experience with that?

Answer (score 4):

The correct entrypoint for annotations on `ApiView` (here `ListAPIView`) is the `get` method, not the `list` method.

This is because `get` is the actual method and `list` is only wrapped to proxy to the mixin.

```py
class ListAPIView(mixins.ListModelMixin, GenericAPIView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

[FAQ entry](https://drf-spectacular.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#using-extend-schema-on-apiview-has-no-effect).

Annotate the `get` method and call `self.list()` yourself, and the parameter will show up.